# PowerMockito whenNew doesn't work with multiple constructors

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

`whenNew` is not working if I have two constructors - one without and one with arguments. In the code excerpt below I need the real constructor to be called a second time, but I get a `NullPointerException` instead.

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class UtilTest {

        @Test
        public void test()throws Exception {
            A a= new A();
            a.setI(10);
            whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(a);

            UtilTest test= new UtilTest();
            test.testA();

        }

        private void testA(){
            A a1= new A();
            System.out.println(a1.getI());
            A a2= new A(50);
            System.out.println(a2.getI());
        } 
    }

    class A{
        int i=1;
        public A(){}

        public A(int i){
            this.i=i;
        }

        public void setI(int i){
           this.i=i;
        }

        public int getI(){
            return this.i;
        }
    }
```

**Output -**

```
10
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: **1)** Unless I add `@PrepareForTest(UtilTest.class)` it will successfully print 10 & 50. **2)** If you don't care about which constructor is called then use `whenNew(A.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(a);`. **3)** If you care about the constructor then define values for each of then **4)** Otherwise give us some context, because it's a bit odd understanding why and what you need.

Comment: Sorry, @Morfic if i am not clear enough. My expected output is 10 and 50. 1) - it will give 1 & 50 2) & 3) i do care about which constructor to mock. 4) My objective to mock the constructor with no arguments but not other one. Kind of partial mock on object creation, dont know if it is possible.

Comment: Not sure that's possible, but unless I'm missing your point you should be able to mock your **A** and return 10 and then 50 for `getI()`. Something along the lines of: `A mockA = mock(A.class); when(mockA.getI()).thenReturn(10, 50); whenNew(A.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockA);`. Don't forget the `@PrepareForTest(UtilTest.class)`

Answer (score 0):

(1) Keep class newInstance(int) method before class manipulations

(2) Try to define both constructors.

```
whenNew(A.class)
    .withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(a);
whenNew(A.class)
    .withArguments(...)
    .doAnswer(call original constructor);
```

Comment: The last chance: private constructors + static factory methods

Comment: Thanks ursa for your prompt replies. Unfortunately,  doAnswer will go into stackoverflow as it will again call the whennew and this will go on. And i cant do anything on class A as it comes from a jar.

Comment: If you keep the reference to the original class.newInstance(int) method and call it from Answer - it will be impossible to get stackoverflow. Do I missed something?